# Время выполнения PHP скрипта

Tags: php

Как правильно считывать время выполнения скрипта и выводить его в браузере?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Со временем есть только одна неувязка: время "запуска" таймера. Либо он идет не в самом начале скрипта, либо он болтается где-то отдельной переменной, и при этом он все равно не захватит то время, которое скрипт инициализровался. Но в целом все делается так:

index.php

```
$start = microtime(true);
// подключаем все необходимые файлы
```

footer.php (или то место, где время нужно вывести)

```
$time = microtime(true) - $start; // теперь в переменной $time содержится float со значением выполнения скрипта в секундах. дело осталось за банальными number_format() и echo.
```

Comment: Мне кажется это ерундой, так как значение постоянно разное, как один и тот же код, при перезагрузке может кардинально менять время выполнения. 

Что по поводу запятых, то текст я набираю с теми же прерываниями, что и про разговоре, поэтому не стоит это публично обсуждать.

Comment: 0.001
0.003
0.000
0.009
0.005
0.000

Comment: время выполнения слишком маленькое, что бы его измерять с помощью microtime.

Comment: @KoVadim как тогда можно измерить ?

Comment: @Евгений  Кузнецов, для того, чтоб время выполнения была одинаковой с точностью до тысячных секунды (*и более*), вам нужна машина наподобие атомных часов или измерение, основанного на использовании строгопериодического излучения галактических источников – пульсаров. Боюсь, что на такой аппарат, вам за всю жизнь не накопить. Поэтому расслабтесь и возьмите среднее арифметическое значений.

Comment: @Евгений  Кузнецов, во-первых, все современные ОС - многозадачные и готовые задачи конкурируют за процессор. Во-вторых, существует время обновления таймера, которое тоже вносит погрешности, особенно при малых величинах. Поэтому точно совпадающее время вы не получите, тем более на таком языке как PHP. Так же при малых величинах смотрят приблизительное среднее время выполнения с прогоном интересующего скрипта по несколько тысяч раз в цикле.

Comment: Только один вопрос. Зачем вам измерять время выполнения, когда у вас сотые секунд? Я аналогичным способом искал, что именно мне "замедляет" PHP скрипт, когда время ответа с 0,3 возросло до 2 - 3 секунд. Вот в таком случаи подобный функционал для небольшого дебага необходим, а вам для чего это? Боитесь, что пользователь вашего сайта не захочет ждать дополнительные 0,0001 секунду?

Answer (score 15):

Кидаем этот код в начало скрипта

```
$start = microtime(true);
```

А вот это в самый конец скрипта (округляется до 4 знака после запятой)

```
echo 'Время выполнения скрипта: '.round(microtime(true) - $start, 4).' сек.';
```