# Что быстрее json_decode или explode?

Tags: php

Что быстрее json_decode или explode?
Информация хранится в виде `1,2,3` есть возможность изменить на `[1,2,3]`
В дальнейшем требуется из этих данных получить массив.
У меня есть два решения

1)Хранить данные `1,2,3` и выводить:

```
$test = '1,2,3';
$test = explode(',', $test);
print_r($test);
```

Результат:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

2)Хранить данные в виде `[1,2,3]` и выводить:

```
$test = '[1,2,3]';
$test = json_decode($test);
print_r($test);
```

Результат:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

Какой из способов более щадящий, либо есть другой?

Comment: Так замерейте скорость выполнения: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/353949/%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-php-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Если логически прикинуть, что в своих операциях делают обе функции, то должно становится очевидным, какая из них будет быстрее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обе одинаково быстрые. Не нужно занимать себя такими бессмысленными вопросами.

Функции не бывают медленными. Медленной бывает архитектура.

- Если объем данных в этих массивах будет небольшим, то не будет никакой разницы, любая функция будет работать быстро.
- Ecли объем данных будет большим, то не будет никакой разницы, любая функция будет работать медленно.

Отсюда вывод - если нас интересует производительность, мы должны следить за объемом данных, а не за тем, какая функция будет их обрабатывать.

Сама идея хранить массивы данных через запятую выглядит костылем, и скорее всего приведет к проблемам в будущем. Не со скоростью, а с написанием кода для их обработки.

Comment: При большом количестве небольших массивов explode вполне может дать прирост производительности и(!!!) уменьшение потребляемой памяти.

Comment: именно поэтому надо заранее думать об архитектуре и не доводить ситуацию до того, чтобы приходилось обрабатывать много массивов

Answer (score 3):

json_decode на порядки более сложная и тяжелая функция, чем explode.

В explode производится всего один проход по строке с наполнением хэш-таблицы. В json_decode происходит синтаксический разбор средствами библиотеки bison с созданием большого количества промежуточных значений.

Но! Как верно отметил Ипатьев, если у вас не высоконагруженная система, то использовать одно вместо другого - это экономия на микро(если не нано)-секундах. С точки зрения организации данных json более предпочтителен.