# Как вывести 30 случайных строк из тектового файла без нагрузки для сервера?

Tags: php

Файл txt - текстовой файл из 10тыс строк русскоязычного текста. Как вывести 30 случайных строк из этого файла без перемешивания? Код ниже выполнял эту функцию, каждый раз перемешивая файл, что затрудняло процесс и страница грузилась долго, учитывая несколько мест ввода скрипта на странице.
Текст кириллица.

Формат вывода:
случайная строка
случайная строка
...
случайная строка (всего 30)

Код, который использовался ранее (не подходит из-за длительности обращений к серверу):

```
<?php
$arr = file('https://site/1.txt');
shuffle($arr);
$res = array_slice($arr, 0, 30);
foreach ($res as $str) {
  $get  = mb_detect_encoding($str, array('utf-8', 'cp1251'));
  echo iconv($get, 'UTF-8', $str);
}
?>
```

или так:

```
foreach($res as $str){
  echo htmlspecialchars($str);
}
?>
```

Очень прошу предложить полный код решения, я сам SEOшник и в ПХП не силен. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если в файле всего 100 строк, то проблема не в этом коде. Он в принципе не должен медленно работать.

Comment: 100 строк, длительность обращений? Это вряд ли. ...Вы как-то очень плохо думаете про язык PHP, если думаете что она такой тормозной.. Проблема вряд ли тут, а в каких-нибудь настройках сервера. А если и тут - то это надо доказать, проанализировав реальную работу этого скрипта. Для этого есть множество способов, например использовать отет отсюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/678412/191482   ...........  А пока, это просто на уровне домыслов ни на чём не основанных

Comment: на самом деле строк больше. я просто для примера привел. в конкретном случае от 5 до 10тыс строк в файле

Comment: вызов скрипта на странице осуществляется не менее 30 раз, поэтому тормозит. вот и прошу помощи

Comment: контент файла меняется? Если нет, то делаете вместо текстового файла пхп файл, куда пишите ваши строки а-ля `<?php return ['123', '234']`. со включенным опкэшем будет брать строки из памяти, Но судя по тому, что строк от 5 до 10тыс, то строки меняются. Хотя это все равно не мешает их в таком виде экспортировать.

Comment: у вас файл вообще на другом севере лежит чтоли? Или зачем вы к нему через хттп обращаетесь ?

Comment: Я бы повесил задание, которое раз в N времени берет файл, читает и пишет в БД. А сам код переписал бы на выборку данных из БД. 10к строк для БД - копейки. Итого данные меняются, выборка идет быстро и процессы независимые.

Comment: А зачем вообще читать из файла? Он статичен? Если нет, то можно раз в минуту (или после его обновления) пересчитывать количество строк, и получать случайное число в диапазоне 0...Х строк. А читать по номеру строки можно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588577/fseek-by-line-not-bytes).

Answer (score -1):

По сути проблемы вам подойдёт алгоритм [Reservoir sampling](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling)

```
*
  S has items to sample, R will contain the result
*/
ReservoirSample(S[1..n], R[1..k])
  // fill the reservoir array
  for i = 1 to k
      R[i] := S[i]

  // replace elements with gradually decreasing probability
  for i = k+1 to n
    j := random(1, i)   // important: inclusive range
    if j <= k
        R[j] := S[i]
```

Однако не могу сказать, подойдёт ли это вам, т.к. если файл изменяется, то весь файл всё равно читать нужно.

Comment: Это python? Человеку нужен PHP

Comment: @Total Pusher Это псевдокод